# Rosbag as a workspace

Tags: ros, python, rosbag, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm creating a rosbag and want to record two topics into a `.bag` file. I am using a Python script to create this. The problem being is that I don't know whether or not I need to create a workspace, so then I could have the following command: `rosrun project bag` which would then record the topics or just have a script that I can run from terminal manually?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111271/rosbag-as-a-workspace/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
use the command tool `rosbag record -a` to record in a bag file.

See:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data

If you really need the API for python, see:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API where read and write from python to a bag file are detailled.

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1